# Reputation is not updated

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I have some daily records of approved edits, which should continuously increase the reputation.

Suggestions as of 18<sup>th</sup> January:

[image: 18 January suggestions]

However, the last successful reputation update was 3 days back:

[image: last successful update]

I know it can take some time to update it, but it was never for 3 days before.

Comment: Could it be possible that you've hit the limit of 1,000 total rep you're allowed to earn from approved edits?

Comment: I believe it is 2000

Comment: It's 1000. Check out this link: https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: You stop earning rep from edits when you hit 2000 rep, but you're also only able to earn a max of 1000 of approved edits.

Comment: But 1000 approved edit, means 2000 reputation, which is not the case

Comment: It's not 1000 approved edits. It's really 500 approved edits, which adds up to 1000 total rep you're able to gain from approved edits.

Comment: Hopefully you don't stop suggesting edits now that you've hit the rep cap :) Your suggested edits are always the most reliable in the review queue. Good job.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to make the posts a little better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### I have some approved edits, which should increase my reputation.

The reputation from approved edits is capped at 1000:

> You gain reputation when:
>
> ...
>
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (**up to +1000 total per user**)

Source [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)